# JavaScript Functions And Events

Tags: javascript, function, dom-events

I'm making a function that takes two inputs and makes a select box from their contents but when I run the code it doesn't work and doesn't give me any errors.
When I run the function by itself and give it the inputs manually it seems to work just fine.

The code:

```js
var start = parseInt(document.getElementById("start")),
  end = parseInt(document.getElementById("end")),
  button = document.getElementById("button");

button.onclick = function(x, y) {
  "use strict";
  var years;
  document.write("<select>");
  for (years = start; years <= end; years++) {
    document.write("<option value=\"" + years + "\">" + years + "</option>");
  };
  document.write("</select>");
};
```

```html
<body>
  <input id="start" type="text" />
  <input id="end" type="text" />
  <button id="button">Make Select Box</button>
</body>
```

Comment: What are those `x` and `y` parameters?

Comment: On a side note, please get used to new ways of appending elements to DOM. `document.write` is not a good way to do this.

Comment: You need to access the input values inside the event handler (i.e. every time when the button is clicked), not just once at the beginning

Answer (score 1):

```
var start = parseInt(document.getElementById("start"))
```

This part is parsing whole HTML Element. You have to extract its value:

```
var start = parseInt(document.getElementById("start").value)
```

This also should happen inside the `onclick` callback. If you'll assign this value before clicking - it'll not change at all.